# What does "*RECURSION*" mean when printing $GLOBALS?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

When I print `$GLOBALS` using this code:

```
<?php print_r($GLOBALS); ?>
```

I get this output:

`Array ( [_GET] => Array ( ) [_POST] => Array ( ) [_COOKIE] => Array ( ) [_FILES] => Array ( ) [GLOBALS] => Array *RECURSION* )`

What does "`*RECURSION*`" mean in this case, and why are `$_SERVER`, `$_REQUEST`, etc. not printed as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this part of PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php#85048):

> Keep in mind that $GLOBALS is, itself, a global variable. So code like this won't work:
>
> ```
> <?php
>     print '$GLOBALS = ' . var_export($GLOBALS, true) . "\n";
> ?>
> ```
>
> This results in the error message: "Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?"

You already have retrieved the whole list - you just cannot display part of it (the one containing a recursion, because you would have timeout rather than anything meaningful).

When it comes to `$_REQUEST`, it is a derivative from `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`, so its content is redundant.

**EDIT**:  There is [an old bug / feature](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29176), that seems to be populating `$GLOBALS` with `$_SERVER` and `$_REQUEST` when they are accessed. So try to access `$_REQUEST` and hope it helps. Anyway, it can be found in `$GLOBALS` after that: ideone.com/CGetH

Comment: i looked at that part already..my question is when its outputting for _POST etc at least in a single run it might have to publish the $_REQUEST, $_SERVER ? too

Comment: @swapnesh: There is [an old bug / feature](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29176), that seems to be populating `$GLOBALS` with `$_SERVER` and `$_REQUEST` when they are accessed. So try to access `$_REQUEST` and hope it helps. Anyway, it can be found in `$GLOBALS` after that: http://ideone.com/CGetH

Comment: add this to your answer and then i will ccaept it ..thx for the info bro :)

Comment: @swapnesh: No problem, happy I helped. I have pasted it into my answer ;)

Comment: Is there a way to print only *RECURSION* array values?

Answer (score 2):

`$GLOBALS` contains itself as an array. In [the PHP reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) you can find the definition of `$GLOBALS`:

> An associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. The variable names are the keys of the array.

**Therefore, it has to contain also itself, which leads to a recursion.**

The other arrays are probably just empty, since nothing else has happened in your script.

There is an old joke about recursion: "To understand recursion, you must understand recursion".

BTW: It outputs _SERVER on my computer.

Comment: Ha ... I just discovered that PHP itself is an Recursive acronyms, since it stand for PHP Hypertext Preprocessor... never noticed before. Got by the Wikipedia effect :-) http://xkcd.com/214/